# Invalid Query. You cannot use 'array_contains' filters with 'not_in' filters

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection named channels.

Users are added to **userIds** array and the record is also saved to field named **serverId**.

I just need a list of newly created or updated rows to update to my local room db.

I update **snapshotTime** field every time any changes occurs.

Previously I used the following code, where *lastTime is the max(snapshotTime) of local room db*

```
FirestoreUtil.chatChannelCollectionRef
    .whereArrayContains("userIds", currentUserId)
    //.whereGreaterThan("snapshotTime", lastTime)
    .orderBy("snapshotTime", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
    .startAfter(lastTime)
    .addSnapshotListener (activity) { snapshots, e ->
        if (e != null) {
            Log.e("exception occurred", "")
            return@addSnapshotListener
        }

        for (dc in snapshots!!.documentChanges) {
            when (dc.type) {
                DocumentChange.Type.ADDED -> {
                    val chatChannel = dc.document.toObject(ChatChannel::class.java)
                    chatChannel.serverId = dc.document.id
                    repository.insertOrUpdateChannel(channelDao, chatChannel)
                    Log.e(TAG, "ADDED chatChannel: ${dc.document.data} - ${dc.document.id}")
                }
                DocumentChange.Type.MODIFIED -> {
                    val chatChannel = dc.document.toObject(ChatChannel::class.java)
                    chatChannel.serverId = dc.document.id
                    repository.insertOrUpdateChannel(channelDao, chatChannel)
                    Log.e(TAG, "MODIFIED chatChannel: ${dc.document.data} - ${dc.document.id}")
                }
                DocumentChange.Type.REMOVED -> {
                    val chatChannel = dc.document.toObject(ChatChannel::class.java)
                    chatChannel.serverId = dc.document.id
                    //MessageDatabase.getDatabase(AjoowebApplication.applicationContext()).runInTransaction {
                    repository.deleteChannel(channelDao, chatChannel)
                    Log.e(TAG, "REMOVED chatChannel: ${dc.document.data} - ${dc.document.id}")
                }
                else -> {
                    Log.e(TAG, "MISSING: ${dc.document.data} - ${dc.document.id}")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

which returns the updated fields but not the new records.

So I tried this query to get the new rows only:

*here channels is a list with all channelsId in local db*

```
FirestoreUtil.firestoreInstance
    .collection(FBCollections.CHANNEL_COL)
    .whereNotIn("serverId", channels)
    .whereArrayContains("userIds", currentUserId)
    .get()
    .addOnSuccessListener (activity) { snapshots ->
        for (dc in snapshots!!.documents) {
            val chatChannel = dc.toObject(ChatChannel::class.java)!!
            chatChannel.serverId = dc.id
            repository.insertOrUpdateChannel(channelDao, chatChannel)
            Log.e(TAG, "LOADED chatChannel: ${dc.data} - ${dc.id}")
        }
    }
```

Now the error encountered is:

> **Invalid Query. You cannot use 'array_contains' filters with 'not_in' filters**

How can I get the newly created records as well ?

Comment: It is [documented here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations) that `not-in` should work with `array-contains`. Trying to reproduce this issue with Node.js, I encountered unexpected error messages due to outdate Firestore version. Can you confirm if the Gradle dependency om.google.firebase:firebase-firestore is on the latest version in your project. Currently it is on [version 22.0.0](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)

Comment: implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.2.0'  
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx:20.0.0'  
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx:19.2.0'  
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:19.5.1'  
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx:22.0.0'